# Pdf not showing proper format after converting doc/docx file to pdf containing images, tables and link

Tags: java, pdf, apache-poi, pdf-generation

I am trying to convert word document to pdf using Apache POI(XWPF) for converting docx file using -

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(inputStream);
PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, outputStream, options);
```

for converting doc files to pdf I am using XDocReport along with itext.

But, When after converting to pdf links,tables and images are not showing properly.

I have also tried other libraries like docx4j but it requires MSOffice to be installed on host system whereas I am using Linux so it is difficult to use docx.

Can anyone please suggest any open source library to deal with doc/docx file for converting to pdf.

Comment: you can use FOP.jar

Comment: that is used for xml to pdf right?

Comment: What versions of `fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.*` classes are you using? Have you tried the latest version `fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core-2.0.2.jar`, `fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-2.0.2.jar`, `fr.opensagres.xdocreport.itext.extension-2.0.2.jar` together with `itext-4.2.1.jar` and `apache poi 4.1.0`?

Comment: I am using 1.0.3 version of opensagres. I will try with 2.0.2 version

Comment: @AxelRichter   foolowing your jar verions i m unable to convert docx file to pdf that contains images and tables.